# Question disappeared

Tags: support, specific-question

Yesterday I took sometime to try to understand a mix up of duplicates, due to a user submitting three times a question, and flagged it for a moderator.

This morning all three questions have disappeared.

I tried the moderator tool, but I could not find the question. As I do not remember the user, I cannot check if he/she also disappeared.

As there were valid answers in one of the three, I am puzzled.

Comment: [These questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/373458/physics-student?tab=questions)?

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes! How did you find them?

Comment: OK, . Thanks, The way I searched for them was through my comments in my activity in my profile, and my comments  had disappeared. I guess it was an interim time for the corrections

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what happened:

At about 6:30 in the morning in Greece,  I entered the site and wanted to see what had happened with my flagging a mix up in the duplicate references. The way I find such interference by me, I go to my activities and check my comments, which have the links . All my comments were gone, and going through the Questions list I could not find highlighted the duplicates I had checked last night.

After John's comment, I checked my activity again, and my comments are there, and so are the three identical questions.

So the questions must have been temporarily not available,  in the process of editing out the errors in the duplicate attributions.